# Gufw configuration for basic usage

Tags: linux, arch-linux, firewall

i have installed recently `Gufw` and `ufw` on my arch linux machine.
i was wondering what is the proper rule configuration for basic usage (what to allow/deny on which ports).

can someone recommend some rules?

Answer (score 1):

Block ALL incoming:

If you are don't know then block all incoming. It may black a service that you did not know you were running (but that is what the fire-wall is for). Only open incoming ports that you intend to use.

There is little value in blocking outgoing ports. (almost always)